# Trying to save to database via ModelForm Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

My form is not saving to the database or at least i know the form is not valid i just dont know why? because it will always skip to the else in the if form.is_valid() (print("didnt work!"))

the view.py:

```
def index(request):
    component = Component.objects.all()
    form = ComponentModelForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ComponentModelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/maintenance')
        else:
            form = ComponentModelForm()
            print("didnt work!")
    context = {
        'components': component,
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'maintenance/index.html', context)
```

forms.py:

```
class ComponentModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    note = forms.CharField(widget=forms.Textarea)
    image = forms.ImageField(error_messages = {'invalid':("Image files only")}, widget=forms.FileInput)
    class Meta:
        model = Component
        fields = ("name",
                  "manufacturer",
                  "model",
                  "serial_number",
                  "price",
                  "note",
                  "image",
                  "parent",)
```

the template form:

```
 {% load widget_tweaks %}
 <form class="component-update-grid" enctype="multipart/form-data" method='POST' action=''>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="component-form-data">
       <span class="component-label-text">Name</span>
       {% render_field form.name class="component-form-data-inputs"  %}
       <span class="component-label-text">Manufacturer</span>
       {% render_field form.manufacturer class="component-form-data-inputs"  %}
       <span class="component-label-text">Model</span>
       {% render_field form.model class="component-form-data-inputs"  %}
       <span class="component-label-text">Serial Number</span>
       {% render_field form.serial_number class="component-form-data-inputs"  %}
       <span class="component-label-text">Price</span>
       {% render_field form.price class="component-form-data-inputs"  %}
       <span class="component-label-text">Note</span>
       {% render_field form.note class="component-form-data-inputs"  %}
       {% render_field form.parent class="component-form-data-inputs "  %}
       <input type="submit" class="button1" value='Create Component' />
    </div>
    <div class="component-form-img">

       <img class="maintenance-component-img" src='{%static 'imgs/sidebar/logo.png'%} ' />

       {% render_field form.image  %}
    </div>
 </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should *not* construct a new form when the form fails: a failed form will render the errors, such that the user knows what is going wrong, so:

```
def index(request):
    component = Component.objects.all()
    form = ComponentModelForm()
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ComponentModelForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('/maintenance')
        else:
            # Don't create a new form!
            print("didnt work!")
    context = {
        'components': component,
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'maintenance/index.html', context)
```

Comment: Thank you, you are awesome, this helped me find the issue which was in the image field i didn't provide the request.FILES i will label this answer as accepted